# Parameters of GetListItems() method while calling SharePoint webservice?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm calling SharePoint web service in asp.net. Following is my code. In that **EmpPortal** is name of service reference.

```
  EmpPortal.Lists L = new EmpPortal.Lists();
  L.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

  XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();

  XmlNode ndQuery = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Query", "");
  XmlNode ndViewFields = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "ViewFields", "");
  XmlNode ndQueryOptions = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "QueryOptions", "");

  ndQueryOptions.InnerXml = 
         "<IncludeMandatoryColumns>FALSE</IncludeMandatoryColumns>" +
         "<DateInUtc>TRUE</DateInUtc>";

  ndViewFields.InnerXml = "<FieldRef Name='ows_Calendar Type' />" +
                          "<FieldRef Name='ows_Title'/>" +
                          "<FieldRef Name='ows_Holiday Type'/>" +
                          "<FieldRef Name='ows_Day'/>" +
                          "<FieldRef Name='ows_Holiday Date'/>";

  ndQuery.InnerXml = "<Where><Gt><FieldRef Name='ows_Holiday Date'/>" +
                "<Value Type= 'DateTime'>2014-01-01T00:00:00</Value></Gt></Where>"; 
XmlNode n = L.GetListItems("Holidays", null, ndQuery,ndViewFields ,null,ndQueryOptions, null);
```

I m facing problem with what Name I should give in FieldRef tag.
because with this code I'm getting exception :
 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException'

So please give me more clarity about parameters of `Lists.GetListItems()`?
and how I should use them for my code.

Comment: do you want get sharepoint list items from ASP.Net?

Comment: Yes Amir in first row only I have mentioned I m callng share point web service.

Answer (score 1):

happy to say friends I got answer to my question

```
            ndViewFields.InnerXml = "<FieldRef Name= 'Calendar Type' />" +
                     "<FieldRef Name='Title'/>" +
                     "<FieldRef Name='Holiday Type' />" +//HERE SPACE IS THERE IN BETWEEN WORDS
                     "<FieldRef Name='Day'/>" +
                     "<FieldRef Name='Holiday Date'/>";  //HERE SPACE IS THERE IN BETWEEN WORDS


                ndQuery.InnerXml = String.Format("<Where><Gt><FieldRef Name='Holiday_x0020_Date'></FieldRef><Value Type='DateTime'>2014-01-01T00:00:00</Value></Gt></Where>");
```

main change required was to replace SPACE with x0020 with prefix and postfix with underscore character as shown in above code.